# Pathing algorithm for a continuous search space?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I'm currently making an RTS game in unity and I need a way to calculate the shortest path between two points on a continuous 2d plane where there are certain obstacles.

I have a start position, an end position, and a function that can test whether a position is valid. I need an algorithm that returns a sequence of points to move through in order to get to the destination.

Most of the pathing algorithms like A* and IDA* that I know of require discretized search spaces. I would divide the plane into a grid myself but I fear that it would result in zig zag patterns that look really unnatural when moving along the diagonal. Is there a way to alleviate this problem or a different pathing algorithm I can use? It doesn't even have to find the absolute shortest path, just a path that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe you will find better solutions at gamedev.SE. Every implementation I've seen so far (not that many) puts arbitrary "nodes" in space, discretizing it. If you're smart (and generous) with your terrain and node placements, it looks somewhat natural.

Comment: What you want is a nav mesh and use A* (or similar, all work) on that. There are many ways to archieve that, from creating it by hand, to fully automatic solutions - all of them too much to describe in detail in this format. But there are many articles on the web. Why cant you use Unitys inbuilt navigation solution?

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to discretize the search space by considering only points interesting for planing - points on the boundaries of the obstacles, for example only the corners of bounding boxes, and then use any of the algorithms you already know.

Another option would be to compute on a grid and then smoothen the best path found on the grid.

Answer (score -3):

You could create a zig-zaggy path then use Pure Pursuit to smooth it.

Comment: Please include more detail.